# python subprocess waiting for grandchild on Windows with stdout set

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pipe, stdout

I have a script that is part of an automated test suite.  It runs very slowly on Windows but not on Linux and I have found out why.  The process that we are testing ('frank') creates a child process (so a grandchild).  The python code won't return until that grandchild process also ends (on Windows - doesn't do this on Linux).  The grandchild process will kill itself off after 5 seconds if there is no parent (it hangs around in case another process talks to it)

I've found I can stop the communicate function from hanging in this way if I don't capture stdout.  But I need stdout.  I read somewhere that the communicate function is waiting for all pipes to be closed.  I know that the stdout handle is duplicated for the grandchild but I can't change the code I'm testing.

I've been searching for a solution.  I tried some creation flags (still in the code) but that didn't help.

This is the cut down test -

```
import os
import sys
import threading
import subprocess


def read_from_pipe(process):
    last_stdout = process.communicate()[0]
    print (last_stdout)

CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008

# start process
command = 'frank my arguments'

cwd = "C:\\dev\\ui_test\\frank_test\\workspace\\report183"

p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     cwd=cwd)

# run thread to read from output
t = threading.Thread(target=read_from_pipe, args=[p])
t.start()
t.join(30)
print('finished')
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Peter.

Comment: Don't bother with `communicate` since you're only using `stdout`. Wait for the child to exit, and then call [`PeekNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779) on the handle (from `msvcrt.get_osfhandle(p.stdout.fileno())`) in order to get the number of bytes available to be read. Trying to read more than what's available will block since it's a synchronous mode file and the pipe has another potential writer, i.e. the grandchild process.

Comment: If you have to get more than a pipe full of data (4 KiB by default), then use a loop that polls `PeekNamedPipe` and reads available data while the child is running.

Comment: @eryksun I had a bit more of a play.  If I wait for the process to end with "p.wait()", I have the same problem as I had with communicate.  It waits until the grandchild finishes.

Comment: Thanks - I think I took your word "Wait" to literally mean the .wait call!  I have now looked at poll and tried that out with a little loop.  That  works as I want it to - I mean, poll() tells me the process has ended even though the grandchild is alive.  I will look at the rest of your suggestion.  I'd been hoping for a simple flag or something!  :-)

Comment: I'm using python 3.x.  I'm not sure exactly which sub rev as this test system normally runs on some build machines that I'd have to check out.

Comment: In Python 3 `wait` has a `timeout` option, which can help to make the loop more efficient by adding a small wait in each pass -- maybe 250 ms is an acceptable amount of delay.

Answer (score 0):

After tips from @eryksun and a lot of Googling, I have this rather complicated lot of code!  At one point, I considered cheating and doing os.system and redirecting to a temp file but then I realised that our test code allows for a command timing out.  os.system would just block forever if the child process doesn't die.

```
import os
import sys
import threading
import subprocess
import time
if os.name == 'nt':
    import msvcrt
    import ctypes

# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160319/python-subprocess-waiting-for-grandchild-on-windows-with-stdout-set for details on Windows code
# Based on https://github.com/it2school/Projects/blob/master/2017/Python/party4kids-2/CarGame/src/pygame/tests/test_utils/async_sub.py

from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD
if sys.version_info >= (3,):
    null_byte = '\x00'.encode('ascii')
else:
    null_byte = '\x00'

def ReadFile(handle, desired_bytes, ol = None):
    c_read = DWORD()
    buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(desired_bytes+1)
    success = ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadFile(handle, buffer, desired_bytes, ctypes.byref(c_read), ol)
    buffer[c_read.value] = null_byte
    return ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError(), buffer.value


def PeekNamedPipe(handle):
    c_avail = DWORD()
    c_message = DWORD()
    success = ctypes.windll.kernel32.PeekNamedPipe(handle, None, 0, None, ctypes.byref(c_avail), ctypes.byref(c_message))
    return "", c_avail.value, c_message.value


def read_available(handle):
    buffer, bytesToRead, result = PeekNamedPipe(handle)
    if bytesToRead:
        hr, data = ReadFile(handle, bytesToRead, None)
        return data
    return b''

def read_from_pipe(process):
    if os.name == 'posix':
        last_stdout = process.communicate()[0]
    else:
        handle = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(process.stdout.fileno())
        last_stdout = b''
        while process.poll() is None:
            last_stdout += read_available(handle)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        last_stdout += read_available(handle)
    print (last_stdout)

# start process
command = 'frank my arguments'

cwd = "C:\\dev\\ui_test\\frank_test\\workspace\\report183"

p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     cwd=cwd)

# run thread to read from output
t = threading.Thread(target=read_from_pipe, args=[p])
t.start()
t.join(30)
print('finished')
```

Comment: `read_available` should be able to use the `process.stdout` file if you either set the `Popen` `bufsize` to 0 or do all of the reads via `stdout.raw.read`.

Comment: For `PeekNamedPipe`, use `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)` instead of `ctypes.windll.kernel32`. If the call fails, get the error via `ctypes.get_last_error()`, which is a more reliable value that's enabled by `use_last_error=True`. Raise an exception via `raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())`. There won't be any unread message bytes for an anonymous pipe; pass that as `None`. You just need the number of available bytes. Indicate this by naming the function `get_available_bytes`.

Comment: You don't need a thread since it's just stdout. Threads are required in Windows to avoid deadlock if we have to read from both stdout and stderr in synchronous mode and can't call  `PeekNamedPipe` to read only what's available.